# When typing into JTextArea, text in JLabel moves

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm making a simple GUI and have a problem. 
This is my code :

```
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
jFrame.setTitle("Simple Editor");
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jFrame.setLocation(50,50);
jFrame.setResizable(true);

Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
jTextArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(470,500));

JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();

box.add(jTextArea);
box.add(jLabel);

jLabel.setText("Font type : " + Main.fontType + " font size : " + Main.size 
         + " background color : " + Main.backgroundColor
         + " font color : " + Main.fontColor);

jFrame.setContentPane(box);
jFrame.pack();
jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

When I typing something in `JTextArea`, text in `JLabel` is moving. I can't figure out how to solve this. Maybe some component between them? Any advice and help is welcome.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an artifact of how the `Box` is calculating sizes and locations. Note that some components and layout managers do not use `setPreferredSize`, or only take it as a hint, or use it as only one part of a computation, or etc. so [it cannot be depended upon as a reliable method to set the size of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

In this case, I would hypothesize what is going on is something like: `BoxLayout` generally uses minimum/maximum sizes, not preferred sizes, and the min/max of a `JTextArea` is computed based on its text content. As the text changes, the size is recalculated so the layout changes too.

In general if you have a text area, you should put it in a `JScrollPane` instead:

```
Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();

JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea);
jScrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(470,500));

JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();

box.add(jScrollPane);
box.add(jLabel);
```

This way when the text content changes in the `JTextArea` it can simply do its thing, recalculating its size, and flow out the side of the scroll pane.

Also see [*How to Use Scroll Panes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), [*How to Use Text Areas*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).

---

Per Andrew's comment, here are a couple ways to set the initial size of the scroll pane which are perhaps more reliable than setting the viewport's preferred size explicitly:

```
// specify rows & columns
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);

// specify preferred scrollable viewport size
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return new Dimension(470,500);
    }
};
```

Comment: `JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea(); .. jScrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(470,500));` should be (adjust numbers to need)  `JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea(4,20); ..` See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the suggestion. The actual reason to do that is that the `JTextArea` rows and columns are (apparently, as I had to go and check) used indirectly by `JScrollPane` to calculate its size. The Q&A you're linking to doesn't say that and quite frankly does an extremely poor job explaining why `setPreferredSize` is actually bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        jLabel.setText(jTextArea.getText());
    }
});
```

where,

- `jTextArea` - your name object of `JTextArea` class
- `jLabel` - your name object of `JLabel` class

You add text in the textarea and text in the label is changing. I think, this code help you to decide your problem.